# Name of pattern and interface for bidirectional implicit operator overload

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, interface, operator-overloading

I recently discovered the wonders of implicit operator overloading in C#. I was wondering, if you have both "ways" of implicit operator overloading, such as:

```
public static implicit operator FooType(int num)
{
    return new FooType(num);
}

public static implicit operator int(FooType fooType)
{
    return fooType.IntValue;
}
```

1. Is there a name for that design pattern?
2. Is there a predefined .NET interface that I can use, say `ICastable<int>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If it is i have never heard of it
2. Operators are static constructs and are resolved at compile time. They cannot be part of any interface

Comment: Not to dis @Eric, but your answer came in slightly first, and you clued me in to statics not being allowed for interfaces. So, thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 6):

1. Not that I'm aware of.
2. You might consider implementing `IConvertible`. (If your class can also be *compared* to things, you might consider implementing `IComparable<T>`.)